# Select one or multiple random SQL rows with a WHERE condition on a large table

Tags: mysql, random, markov-chains

I've read http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/ that was also suggested as answer to [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595062/how-to-order-results-of-a-query-randomly-select-random-rows-mysql/5595072#5595072) about selecting a random row from a large table.

However, I now wonder how this technique can be combined with selecting only the rows that also have another field set to a certain value.

For my case, I'm tyring to build a Markov chain. My table has an `id` column that is the auto-increment primary index. It also has a `snippet` column, that stores the new part of the string that is to be added, but only if the  `prev_snippet` column is correct.

This means that I want to select a random row from the table that also has `prev_snippet` set to some string I already have. How can I do so, efficiently?

Comment: A lot depends on you now 'random' you need to it be. Truly random, or only mostly random. Say there are 4 matching rows, its it really important that always get each one 25% of the time. Or does it not matter if some results tend to be favoured over others?

Comment: Also how selective is your 'filter'? i.e. is it always highly selective (few results per prev_snippet), or are there some prev_snippet that have hundreds/thousands of results?

Comment: It does not matter if it is not fully equally distributed. The selectiveness of the filter is however highly varying: The current implementation uses the last two words for comparison. When the previous words are 'of the', for instance, there might be many results returned.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, if you dont care about truly random, then the idea in that linked post, is probably pretty good. as long as index on the `prev_snippet` column!

But because its still completely indepentat use of random, you could end up getting no row in the result, even though there is one. ie each time the filter runs, it just happens to always exclude.

franky, would just try using `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`, it will probably work pretty well. its the size of the resultset that is most important, not the initial table size.